# Better Markov bound

Tags: probability, inequality

Given $X$ a random variable such that $X>0$, $E[\frac{1}{X}]=1$ and $E[X]=2$, is there a better way to bound $P(X \ge a)$, where $a\ge3$, than to use Markov's inequality and get $\frac{2}{a}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do better. For example, consider $Y=4X+1/X-4$. AM-GM gives $Y\geq 0$, and the conditions we have imply $\mathbb{E}(Y)=5$. Also, since $a\geq 2$, whenever $X\geq a$ we also have $Y\geq 4a+1/a-4$. Thus applying Markov's inequality to $Y$ gives $$\mathbb{P}(X\geq a)\leq\frac{5}{4a+1/a-4};$$ this is an improvement on $2/a$ in the range you wanted. For $a=3$, it gives a bound of $0.6$, which is best possible: it could be that $X=3$ with probability $0.6$ and $X=0.5$ with probability $0.4$.

You can do even better by writing $Y=k^2X+1/X-2k$ and choosing the best possible value of $k\in [0,a]$ for the particular value of $a$ you are interested in ($k=2$, as above, is the optimal choice for $a=3$).

Answer (score 0):

You have quite several such inequalities here :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality

But I'm afraid that without any further assumptions on $X$, you can't get anything better.